# Graphical output in Perl

Tags: perl, graphics

A very simple question but just not some thing I have done before and that I have been playing with on and off for a while now.

The basic outline is that I have been playing with different ways of generating procedural based star scapes with the idea that it can generate displays that contain “constellations” that orbit with in a much large field.

The eventual idea is to hook up a laser projector (or two), but you run these using DACs and Galvos. in the mean time I want to simple output to a standard monitor and while I can do this with C# and Visual Basic .NET, graphical output from Perl is not something I have ever done.

Can any one point me in the right direction of what I should be looking at? I just want to create an X by Y window that I can map the starscape array to.

Comment: So why Perl in the first place?

Comment: What OS? What output device? It's likely there's a module somewhere on CPAN that does what you need; see [meta::cpan](https://metacpan.org/).

Comment: Try starting with [SDL](https://metacpan.org/search?q=sdl).

Comment: As to why perl.. I started playing with this in windows hence the C# and VB.net. But I want the final version to run on a raspberry pi which is linux based. And Perl is the only language I can even pretend to have experience of here. As I mentioned in the final I would expect to output to a DAC to run laser galvos, which is basically out putting a series of values the DAC converts in to voltages. very different from displaying to a screen.

Comment: OS either windows or Linux (Debian based), and out put to a standard monitor/desktop either full screen or windowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gtk, Qt or other toolkit to create GUI for Perl applications. I tried [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org). The installation was not so smooth on Windows, but when I got it running, it was pretty much easy to use. The Gtk bindings for Perl can be installed from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~xaoc/Gtk2-1.247/lib/Gtk2.pm).